# Pass data to Flutter View Controller

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, dart

I have added flutter to a native iOS code. I have UIButton and on pressing this button, I am presenting a FlutterViewController. I have been following [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/add-flutter-screen?tab=no-engine-vc-swift-tab).

Here's my code for presenting the FlutterViewController:

```
@objc
@IBAction func openProfile() {
    print("open profile")
    
    lazy var flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "patient_profile_engine")
    
    flutterEngine.run(withEntrypoint: "", libraryURI: "");
    
    let profileVC =
            FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    present(profileVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This code is working fine and the flutter view is opening and since I haven't specified and entry point yet so it using the main.dart.

The problem is that I need to pass some information to the Flutter dart code. e.g. a dictionary `["patient_id": "123456"]` during the initialization.

I will have to do the same in Android native Java code as well.

Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to write a [platform channel](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to communicate between the native code and the flutter engine.

An alternative, for this purpose, would be to use [runWithEntrypoint:initialRoute:](https://api.flutter.dev/objcdoc/Classes/FlutterEngine.html#/c:objc(cs)FlutterEngine(im)runWithEntrypoint:initialRoute:) method to start the engine, encode the data into the initial route, and parse it on the flutter side.